# Using Google Cloud Client Library and Google App Engine SDK Together

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use the [Google Cloud Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries) on Google App Engine. However, the Cloud Client Library and the App Engine SDK use `google` as an import name, and there are naming conflicts. How do I get them to work together?

When I try importing a Google Cloud Client Library module, I get the following error:

```
     >> import google.cloud.datastore
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\[...]\libs\google\cloud\datastore\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
         from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch
     ImportError: No module named cloud.datastore.batch
```

The reason this import error occurs is because the name `google` has already been imported from the App Engine SDK. This can be confirmed by running the command:

```
     >>> print google.__path__
     ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\ platform\\google_appengine\\google']
```

Notice that the path points to the SDK.

Any ideas on how to resolve this name conflict?

Comment: Have you tried to install google-cloud package using [vendoring](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) ?